# Why Session objects are not removed after Timeout period in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, asp.net-4.0

### Why Session objects are not removed after Timeout period?

I am using Asp.Net 4.0 and Session state is configured as shown below.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieless="false" timeout="5"
                  allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" 
                  sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SqlExpress;initial catalog=App_SessionState;user id=sa;password=xxxxxxxx"/>
```

If I have not activity in browser for about 10 mins, shouldn't the Session object be removed. But after 10 mins I can still access the Session variable. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

If I access a session variable after 10 mins as shown below shouldn't I get **NULL**

```
  var myObj = Session["MyKey"] as MyClass;
```

mObj is not NULL after 10 mins.

Comment: Did you mean you see the variable in the database, not in memory? I do not know what mechanism is needed for managing the session in sqlserver, but what matters is the session object visible in asp.net. Verify that the SessionStart and SessionEnd events take place properly

Comment: As a quick test, see if you get the expected result after 25 minutes (the default timeout being 20 minutes). Post the results here. You are not using forms authentication or any other mechanism that might enforce it's own timeout?

Comment: @Paul : There is no authentication there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a stored procedure installed called `DeleteExpiredSessions`, called from the job `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiredSessions`, and is executed every minute (if I read the InstallSqlState.sql file correctly).

The procedure basically calls `DELETE FROM ASPStateTempSessions WHERE Expires < GETUTCDATE()`

So, if objects aren't removed, check the Expires column, and verify that you're comparing with the *utc* date. If in doubt, do a `SELECT * FROM ASPStateTempSessions WHERE Expires < GETUTCDATE()`. Also, make sure that your `ASPState_Job_DeleteExpiresSessions` is enabled and working.

A quick (and totally unconfirmed idea); do SQL Server Express come with the SQL Agent? Is it enabled and able execute scheduled jobs?

Answer (score 2):

The "session" is never "null", but after the timeout has expired, the session object is emptied (or re-instantiated), another session is automatically started (you can check this by handling SessionEnd and SessionStart events), and you will always have a reference to a session object.
Does not happen? Still you see previous session's data?

Comment: You won't get any of those events fired for SQL server session mode

Answer (score 0):

To add onto what Simon said, If there is no SQL Server Agent running there will be no clearing of session values unless a stored procedure inside of the database is actually executed.
I don't think SQL Server express has the Agent so an automated job is not possible.

If you have control of the server then I would suggest setting up a scheduled task through windows that executes the stored procedure or job that clears your expired sessions.  I don't know the exact name of the stored procedure right now but it should be named fairly obvious to it's purpose.

So your options are to upgrade to a version of SQL server that has the SQL Server Agent available or set something up to manually execute the stored procedure to clear expired sessions.

Alliteratively you can use InProc sessions, which are cleared automatically.  But I assumed since InProc is the default there is a reason why you switched to SQL Server.